# "fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense" in ZSH alias function

Tags: git, zsh

I have the below alias and function set up, and when I run `gca "My commit message"` I get `fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense`.  Any idea how I can fix this?

```
alias gca='gca'

function gca() {
    git commit -am "$1"
}
```

Running `gca -x` outputs the following:

```
gca -x
error: unknown switch `x'
usage: git commit [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...

    -q, --quiet           suppress summary after successful commit
    -v, --verbose         show diff in commit message template

Commit message options
    -F, --file <file>     read message from file
    --author <author>     override author for commit
    --date <date>         override date for commit
    -m, --message <message>
                        commit message
    -c, --reedit-message <commit>
                        reuse and edit message from specified commit
    -C, --reuse-message <commit>
                        reuse message from specified commit
    --fixup <commit>      use autosquash formatted message to fixup specified commit
    --squash <commit>     use autosquash formatted message to squash specified commit
    --reset-author        the commit is authored by me now (used with -C/-c/--amend)
    -s, --signoff         add Signed-off-by:
    -t, --template <file>
                        use specified template file
    -e, --edit            force edit of commit
    --cleanup <default>   how to strip spaces and #comments from message
    --status              include status in commit message template
    -S, --gpg-sign[=<key-id>]
                        GPG sign commit

Commit contents options
    -a, --all             commit all changed files
    -i, --include         add specified files to index for commit
    --interactive         interactively add files
    -p, --patch           interactively add changes
    -o, --only            commit only specified files
    -n, --no-verify       bypass pre-commit and commit-msg hooks
    --dry-run             show what would be committed
    --short               show status concisely
    --branch              show branch information
    --porcelain           machine-readable output
    --long                show status in long format (default)
    -z, --null            terminate entries with NUL
    --amend               amend previous commit
    --no-post-rewrite     bypass post-rewrite hook
    -u, --untracked-files[=<mode>]
                        show untracked files, optional modes: all, normal, no. (Default: all)
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Can you run it with `-x` and post the result as an update to your question?

Comment: What's the purpose of the alias?

Comment: @user1934428 I have updated my question.
@chepner Basically I just want a quick way to `git commit` all changed files (hence the `-a`) with a message I specify.

Comment: You should not pass -x to your *function* (this doesn't make sense), but run the shell with -x; but anyway, I think that I now see the error. See my separate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `gca` was an alias established by the git plugin for `oh-my-zsh`.   After the `source oh-my-zsh.sh` line in my `~/.zshrc`, I `unalias gca`, and alias `gca='git commit -am'` and everything works as expected.  Note to all future readers - always put your custom aliases after things such as `oh-my-zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an alias and a function with the same name, PLUS the alias defines itself. This doesn't make sense.

Remove the alias definition. It should then work, but if you continue to encounter problems, put a

```
set -x
```

in the first line of your function (and a `set +x` at the end) and run it again.

Alternatively,  you can drop the function and do everything by alias:

```
alias gcd='git commit -am'
```

Comment: I first tried `alias gca='git commit -am'` and got the `fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.` error when running `gca "My commit message"`.  I have eliminated the function completely when doing this, and I'd greatly prefer doing it without the function.  Changing the alias to `gcd` causes the same issue. Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Would it be possible that my other aliases `gc='git commit'` and `gd='git diff'` in `~/.zshrc` are interfering here?  Or is the issue somewhere else?  When I change `gca='git commit -am'` to `gcam='git commit -am'` it works as expected.  Why is this happening so I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: Change it back to *gca*, see whether the bug occurs again, and if it does, do a `type gca`. What do you get in return?

Comment: Changed the alias back to `gca` and ran `type gca` - I get this: `gca is an alias for git commit -v -a`.  That makes no sense, the .zshrc file clearly has that alias as `alias gca='git commit -am'`.  I have removed the function, and `source`'d since making these changes.  Changing the alias to `gcam` and running `type gca` still outputs `gca is an alias for git commit -v -a`, even though `gca` is no where to be found in .zshrc.  What is going on?

Comment: It means that your zsh sees a redefinition of this alias later on. I suggest that your trace your .zshrc with `-x`. For instance, you can put a `set -x` on top of your .zshrc. You should find at some point that - unless a `set +x` happens to be encountered - the `gca` is defined again.

Comment: Found the issue - the `oh-my-zsh` git plugin must use `gca` as an alias, because after I source `oh-my-zsh.sh`, `unalias gca`, and `alias gca='git commit -am'`, everything works as expected.  I have learned a very valuable lesson - all my custom aliases go after `oh-my-zsh` or anything similar.